# Dynamically changing WPF ListView ItemsPanel & ItemsContainerStyle

Tags: wpf, listview, controltemplate, itemspaneltemplate

I have a ListView in XAML which displays its source collection in a GridView (with columns) fashion.
However I intend to use the same ListView to display the source collection may be in a grid of  images, or some card view.
I want the ListView to change itself based on a ComboBox selection. So say for ComboBox value 1 ListView should display a  GridView, for value 2 ListView should display card view.
Currently my ListView specifies a GridView set as its View property:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" Width="450" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="LastName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Ip Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=IpAddress}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I would like to know how can I change the ListView to display different views based on ComboBox triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView `View` is a DependencyProperty of type `ViewBase`. So, what you can do is **create your  own custom views and can set it via DataTrigger on combobox selected item**.

Microsoft already has sample available for it online which you can download from [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7766).

**OR**

May be you can *define two separate ListView's in resources* as two seperate DataTemplates.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="GridViewTemplate">
      <ListView/> <!-- GridView -->
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="CardViewTemplate">
      <ListView/> <!-- CardView -->
   </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

and have one `ContentControl` in place and you can swap its Content based on selected value in combobox.

```
<ContentControl>
   <ContentControl.Style>
      <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
         <Setter Property="Content"
                 Value="{StaticResource GridViewTemplate}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedValue}" Value="Value2">
                  <Setter Property="Content"
                          Value="{StaticResource CardViewTemplate}"/>
               </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Both appear to be perfect solutions...but if I had to make a choice which one should I choose...according to you which of the solution would be better to implement...from the perspective of performance.

Comment: If you have more than two templates, I would suggest first approach otherwise second approach would suffice your needs. Performance impact seems same to me since at runtime you are changing template. In first case you are changing ListView template and in second case ContentControl template.